# Convert numpy iterator to dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, scipy

I am iterating through two arrays with Numpy by following code

```
for position, force in np.nditer([positions,forces]):
    print("(x,y) = (%f,%f)" % (position, force))
```

but now I need it is a dictionary as

```
{
  1: "(x,y) = (2,3)",
  2: "(x,y) = (7,4)",
  3: "(x,y) = (1,2)",
  4: "(x,y) = (9,8)",
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create the dictionary with the help of `enumerate` within a dict comprehension :

```
{i: "(x,y) = (%f,%f)" % t for i, t in enumerate(np.nditer([positions,forces]), 1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#tracking-an-index-or-multi-index
`nditer` does have a way of tracking the index, but you loose some of the convenience.  It has to be used in the `c` style `while` loop:

```
d={}
it=np.nditer([a,b],flags=['c_index'])
while not it.finished:
     d[it.index]='%s, %s'%it[:]
    it.iternext()
```

So wrapping the iterator in `enumerate` is probably easier to remember and use.  Or just keep track of your own counter  (`cnt=0` .... `cnt += 1`).